# Generating Eclipse project files with Maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven-2

When I try and generate the Eclipse project files using `mvn eclipse:eclipse` I get the following error:

> Internal error in the plugin manager executing goal
>   'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-eclipse-plugin:2.9-SNAPSHOT:eclipse': Unable to load the mojo
>   'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-eclipse-plugin:2.9-SNAPSHOT:eclipse'
>   in the plugin 'org
>   .apache.maven.plugins:maven-eclipse-plugin'.
>   A required class is missing:
>   org/codehaus/plexus/resource/loader/ResourceNotFoundException

It appears that I'm using version 2.9-SNAPSHOT of the Maven Eclipse plugin. My guess is that there is a bug in this version of the plugin and if I use a stable release (instead of a snapshot), the problem will be resolved. Is there a way that I can change the version of this plugin I'm using, or is this problem unrelated to the version of the Eclipse plugin?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Either use the fully qualified name of the plugin to specify the version:

```
$ mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-eclipse-plugin:2.8:eclipse
```

Or edit the `~/.m2/plugin-registry.xml` file (for advanced users, make a backup).

Or try the `-npr,--no-plugin-registry` options to tell maven to not use `~/.m2/plugin-registry.xml` for plugin versions:

```
$ mvn -npr eclipse:eclipse
```

But I don't guarantee a successful result. See the [Introduction to the Plugin Registry](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-plugin-registry.html) for more details.

Or remove the version `2.9-SNAPSHOT` from your local repository:

```
$ rm -rf ~/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/2.9-SNAPSHOT
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the problem still persists and the selected answer did not help me, as Maven always wanted to fetch the newest version available, which is the faulty 2.9-SNAPSHOT.

I had to manually specify the working version 2.8 in my POM, like so:

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.8</version>
   <configuration>
...
```

Comment: The problem lies in different resolution of snapshot artifacts in Maven 2 and Maven 3, which supports snapshot classifiers like a date. Unfortunately this can only be resolved by the repository maintainer, see http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/maven-3-snapshot-resolving-td3238639.html - upgrading to Nexus 1.8 should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The solutions mentioned in the accepted answer does not seems to work. Using no plugin registry, it always tries to use the latest version, and re-download it you try to delete it.

I solved the problem by updating the file

> .m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/maven-metadata-central.xml

You're not supposed to edit this file, but if it was using the 2.9-SNAP instead of 2.9, it probably means that this file specified 2.9-SNAP at the latest instead of the 2.9